# Jquery datepicker goes to 1954 after 2013

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Help! My datepicker is going to 1954 after dec. 2013. I need the datepicker to go at least a full year ahead of whatever the "current date" would be. I dont know what the deal is with this code, but this is what I have.

```
var cur_year=(new Date().getFullYear())
var cur_month = (new Date().getMonth())


                $(function(){
                var pickerOpts = {
                    showOn: "button",
                    buttonImage: "/images/calendar.png",
                    buttonImageOnly: true,
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    yearRange: "-60:+0"
                }; 
                 $(".date_box").datepicker(pickerOpts);
```

});

I got rid of a bunch of extra crap, so the brackets may be wrong. I simply need the date to continue on to the next year after Dec 2013. Next year I need it to go to 2014 after Dec 2014.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
yearRange: "-60:+1"
```

If you need it to go even further, change `+1` to a higher number.

As per [the doco](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange), `yearRange` sets:

> The range of years displayed in the year drop-down: either relative to today's year `("-nn:+nn")`, relative to the currently selected year `("c-nn:c+nn")`, absolute `("nnnn:nnnn")`, or combinations of these formats `("nnnn:-nn")`. Note that this option only affects what appears in the drop-down, to restrict which dates may be selected use the `minDate` and/or `maxDate` options.

Comment: Thanks! That was simple, I will + rep you in a min!

Answer (score 3):

Just guessing, but:

1954 - 2013:

```
           yearRange: "-60:+0"
```

1959 - 2014:

```
            yearRange: "-55:+1"
```

1954 - 2018:

```
            yearRange: "-60:+5"
```